# What is difference between react-router 4.0, react-router-dom and react-router-redux?

Tags: reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I am implementing routing in react-application. I am confused between the advantage of react-router 4.0 over react-router-redux. I am also confused by  react-router-dom.

What are the advantages and disadvantages of react-router-redux, react-router 4.0 and react-router-dom over each other?

Answer (score 41, accepted):

`react-router` v4 is base, building block. Provides API for creating routing solution.

`react-router-dom` is wrapper around `react-router`. It is supposed to be run in browser.

`react-router-redux` offers so called "controlled router", bound to `redux` store. State changes (navigation) could be controlled by dispatching `redux` actions as well as by clicking on links.

Your best bet is to start with `react-router-dom` (which pulls in `react-router` for you by default).

Comment: now my confusion is why I should use react-redux-router because by using react router 4.0 we can access the location and history information by using this.props.history. push('/') In which scenario it is mandatory to use react-redux-router?

Comment: You absolutely don't have to use `react-router-redux`. It's completely optional. You don't have to use it even if you use `redux` for state management.

Comment: yes we are using redux for state management, then I think it is not required to use react-redux-router. Thanks

Comment: But I think react-redux-router will be useful for maintaining the state in page refresh, if we are not using local storage. Am I right?

Comment: In my experience, `react-router-redux` is "only" useful for managing location (push, goBack) as response to actions. You can read location state regardless.

Comment: I'm confused too. I agree with @jack123 for persistence consideration. Redux also allows Time Travel (https://medium.com/the-web-tub/time-travel-in-react-redux-apps-using-the-redux-devtools-5e94eba5e7c0). I'd rather stick to vanilla v4 in so far as Time Travel does not work out of the box in my dev tools :/

Answer (score 33):

**Very very simple explanation!!!**

1. No need to use **`react-router`** directly.
2. **`react-router-dom`** is made for "Web application" and **`react-router-native`** is made for "react native mobile apps".
3. `react-router-dom` & `react-router-native` **uses `react-router` at core**.
4. react-router-dom works **perfectly** fine with Redux, **NO NEED of `react-router-redux`.** (confirmed by **Dan abramov** - creator of Redux)
5. **Extra Benefit of `react-router-redux`** is you can keep your router in sync with application state.
6. **In nutshell** - history + store (redux) → `react-router-redux`

Answer (score 8):

- [react-router](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router) exports shared, core modules for native ([react-router-native](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-native)) and web development ([react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom))
- Use [react-router-dom](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/blob/master/packages/react-router-dom) for web development
- Use r[eact-router-native](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-native) for native development
- Use [react-router-redux](https://github.com/ReactTraining/react-router/tree/master/packages/react-router-redux) to integrate [react-redux](https://github.com/reactjs/react-redux) and [react-router](https://github.com/reacttraining/react-router) in order to, for instance, navigate via `store.dispatch()`

Comment: Why we should use react-redux-router is it only for maintain the routing state in store but in react-router 4.0 we can access the routing information as a props, then what is the need of react-redux-router?

Comment: no real  need in my opinion, I don't use it. the router alone is powerful enough.

Comment: that's what my confusion was because router alone is powerful so react-redux-router is not so useful if using redux for our state management. Thanks